# How to fix "no module named 'app_one'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a Python package with the following structure.

```
>python_package       # package root directory
    >app_one          # subpackage directory
        >__init__.py
        >views.py
   
    >app_two          # another subpackage directory
        >__init__.py
        >views.py
```

Code for `app_one/views.py`:

```
def show(): 
    print('do something')
```

Codes for `app_two/views.py`:

```
from app_one.views import show
show()
```

The problem is, whenever I try to run `views.py` of `app_two` from the terminal, I get an error

> No module named 'app_one'

But when I open the package `python_package` in the PyCharm IDE, I'm getting no issue, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because, the path to the file `app_one` is not in the current path, and you have to add it to the path using `sys.path.append` Try :

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./app_one')
from views import show
show()
```

Comment: but when I use an IDE like I pycharm, I'm getting no error. Why ??

Comment: I believe PyCharm automatically takes care of the paths, so that no manual intervention is need

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same directory structure as you had and gave it a try and it is working.

I think what you were missing is that adding this line before you import in `app_two/views.py`:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(__file__ + "../../../"))
```

Please have a look at the attached image which has detailed information

[image]

Comment: When posting text, please always post is as text, not as an image of text. Images of text cause problems for users wanting to copy+paste, or users with screen-readers. Search engine bots also cannot cope with them.

Comment: @halfer, I did not know. Thank you very much for your suggestions and I will keep in mind next time