# ImportError: cannot import name 'build' from partially initialized module 'binarytree'

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

My guess is that, this is caused most likely due to a circular import.

```
from binarytree import build
n = build([4,5,3,7,8,2,1])

print(n)
```

**Error:**-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\ml and ai in python\binarytree.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binarytree import build
  File "d:\ml and ai in python\binarytree.py", line 1, in <module>
    from binarytree import build
ImportError: cannot import name 'build' from partially initialized module 'binarytree' (most likely due to a circular import) (d:\ml and ai in python\binarytree.py)
```

Comment: Please enter more description to the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)