# Pycharm module import fails when running tests, but not when running main script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a pycharm project with the following structure

```
root
|_test.py
|_code
     |_a.py
     |_b.py
```

When I run a.py, it imports a function from b.py and it runs correctly.

However, when I run test.py (which imports functions from a and therefore from b, I get the following error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named b.py

Does anybody know why this might happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)

Comment: Not really. My problem happens when I run test.py, which imports from a, which imports from b. Then I get the error. However, when I run a.py directly, it works well.