# How do I import internal packages using Python __init__.py file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to test Python modules. Currently, the file structure is like the following displayed:

```
project
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
├── p.py
├── package1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
└── package2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    └── module3.py
```

In the **module3.py**, I would like to import the functions defined in **module2.py**. I believe I just need to use `from package1.module2 import function_name`. However, that doesn't work and the error is *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'*.

BTW, I am using Python3.6 for the testing.

Comment: First of all, dynamically add `project` path to PYTHON PACKAGE/MODULE SEARCH PATH then try. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any solution where I don't have to bother **sys**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory path to your sys.path or PYTHONPATH, the following code would work.
In your module3.py, add this:

```
import os, sys
ab_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../package1'))
sys.path.append(ab_path)
```

Then you can do `from module2 import function_name` after it.

Comment: Thanks! That's basically my current solution. But what if I don't want to bother **sys** library? I think there are such ways provided in the [official website](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#tut-packages). The problem is that it doesn't work for me even though I have the same file structure.