# Invalid relative import to parent folder

Tags: python-3.x

Given the following folder structure

```
scripts
    __init__.py
    prepare_dot_env.py
    random_folder
        __init__.py
        index.py
```

Take the import statement `from ..prepare_dot_env import prepareDotEnvBot` in `scripts/random_folder/index.py`.

When running `python index.py` inside `scripts/random_folder`, the `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package following exception` is thrown.

According to the [specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports), assuming that both `__init__.py` files are empty, this should be fine. What's the catch here?

Comment: How did you execute ``index.py``? Did you run the file, or did you run the module using the ``python3 -m`` switch? Note that `.`s in relative imports are *not* file system operations ("one folder up") but package operations ("one package up")..

Comment: tried both with no success. same error, a bit more verbose with the -m flag with a deeper stacktrace @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)

Comment: Please show how exactly you execute ``index.py`` - e.g. ``python3 -m index``, ``python3 -m random_folder.index``, or ``python3 -m scripts.random_folder.index``?

Comment: I had it working through `sys.path` append operations but I am looking towards refactoring that workaround due to pep8 constraints. @RoshinRaphel

Comment: edited the question @MisterMiyagi. hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Execute the file as a module of the package:

```
$ python3 -m scripts.random_folder.index
```

If the package is not installed, this must be done from the folder containing `scripts/` or by adding this folder to `PYTHONPATH`.

---

Relative paths work via package operations, not file system operations. A `.` means "one package up", not "one folder up". This means a relative `.` requires information about the current package position. [The `__package__` attribute contains this information](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__):

> This attribute is used instead of `__name__` to *calculate explicit relative imports* for main modules, as defined in PEP 366. It is expected to have the same value as `__spec__.parent`.

The required information is set by qualified imports including the `-m` flag:

```sh
$ # script content: package metadata and import
$ cat scripts/random_folder/index.py
print(__package__)
print(__name__)
from ..prepare_dot_env import bar
print(bar)
$ # script as package member
$ python3 -m scripts.random_folder.index
scripts.random_folder
__main__
Placeholder to demonstrate import
$ # script as standalone executable
$ python scripts/random_folder/index.py
None
__main__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/random_folder/index.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..prepare_dot_env import bar
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: interesting. let's say I want it to imported as a package. what's missing to do so? setup files for both directories or just the parent, i.e., `scripts`?

Comment: ended up installing it as a local package since it better suits my needs and is now working fine without needing to append paths to sys. your help was invaluable.