# How to solve ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package?

Tags: python, import, importerror

I want to make my Project structured and ordered.
It looks like that:
[image: My Project's structure]

In the `scraper.py` I am importing functions from packages at the same level:

```
from scripts.scraping.web_scraping.web_scraper import get_data_from_web, COMMON_PLANT_DISEASES_URL
from scripts.scraping.image_scraping.image_scraper import get_data_from_images, IMAGES_PATH
from scripts.scraping.export_excel.export_excel import save_excel
```

All of the **init**.py contain according lines:

```
from . import export_excel
from . import image_scraper
from . import web_scraper
```

I tried using relative imports:

```
from .web_scraping.web_scraper import get_data_from_web, COMMON_PLANT_DISEASES_URL
from .image_scraping.image_scraper import get_data_from_images, IMAGES_PATH
from .export_excel.export_excel import save_excel
```

however I get the `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` error.

**EDIT**
I added **init**.py to all scripts subfolders, including the scripts folder:

[image: Edit_v1]

But still I get the same error while trying the relative import.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It looks like you need an __init__.py in the scraping directory

Comment: @EricTruett and what should i include inside?

Comment: How do you execute this code?

Comment: it can be empty. The init file makes the folder become a package

Comment: @UdenduAbasili I added an empty scraping/__init__.py but the same results.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I run the scraper.py

Comment: @napuzba I totally gave up after no solution was suitable for me. I used absolute imports

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid relative import to parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772923/invalid-relative-import-to-parent-folder)