# Module not found error while running Python code in terminal

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am getting a Module Not Found error while running my Python code from the terminal.

My Project Structure:

```
Project
../py_configs
  __init__.py
  conf.py
../src
  check.py
```

To automatically add module path to PATH:

`py_configs/__init__.py`

```
import os
import sys

path = os.path.join((os.path.dirname(__file__))).replace('\\', '/')
sys.path.extend([path.replace("/","\\"),path])
```

`src/check.py`

```
from py_configs import conf
```

**Error**

```
Terminal - src directorty: python -m check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\ExperimentProject\src\check.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py_configs import conf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_configs'
```

Comment: "I know it seems like a duplicate question but please it is not!" Did you search for other questions about importing? What was different about them / why were they not helpful for you?

Comment: They all talk about adding a module in PYTHONPATH and PATH the manual way and most of them are for PyCharm and not Terminal :(

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of `relative import`? Try using that for your search. Separately: do you understand conceptually how these `sys.path` alterations are supposed to work? Did you verify in your code that `path` has the value you expect, before modifying `sys.path` with it? Also, you do understand that PATH and PYTHONPATH are Windows-specific concepts, and also nothing that you would work with from inside your Python code, right?

Comment: Yes @KarlKnechtel , I print the paths in sys.path in the init module when I call it from Pycharm and that module path is present, I believe the same thing is happening when calling a program from terminal. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Readers here would like question authors to be open to the possibility that a duplicate question exists on Stack Overflow. We tend to think that it is not possible to make a blanket declaration that the new question is definitely not a duplicate, since it is not possible to have checked all 20M questions on the site. Rather, it is better to be open to specific duplicate suggestions, and then give them an honest appraisal if they are made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)

Comment: unfortunately, no! @RoshinRaphel I still get No Module Found Error when I run the code in terminal

Comment: please have a look at this. It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62832393/module-not-found-error-while-running-python-code-in-terminal

Comment: Please have a look at this post. few mins ago I have posted an answer but accidentally I have copy-pasted a different link which ends up keep coming here. Since I am new here I don't know how to delete it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one/68043322#68043322

Comment: @vasadia: to delete one of your own comments, hover your mouse over the comment, and a "Delete" link will appear after it. Click that link, and answer "OK" to the confirmation box.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error, I found the solution by deleting the python and the library and reinstalling the higher version. Maybe it will work if you try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).