# Python local package import fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to set up a python3 project with unit tests. I set up a folder structure so that the source files and test files are on the same level in the folder structure. In the source code folder I added an **init**.py file so that I can import it into the test classes. The setup that I ended up with is the following.

```
root_folder
|--source_code
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- submodule1
|  |   -files
|  |-- submodule2
|      -files
|--test_folder
|  |--unit
|   --integration
```

To import the **source_code** module into the test scripts I use `from source_code import submodule1.`, and I run the tests from the **root_folder**. When I run the tests however with the current working directory set up to be the **root_folder**, the test scripts can not import the **source_code** module. This problem only happens when I use the standard python3 REPL. If I run in the same manner with the ipython3 REPL from the Jupyter project, the importing works perfectly fine.

While this is not a deal breaker I would like to have the project not depend on another on another REPL due to improper project setup.

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

```
root_folder
|--source_code
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |-- submodule1
|  |   -files
|  |-- submodule2
|      -files
|--test_folder
|  |-- __init__.py
|  |--unit
|   --integration
```

I also changed the structure to have an **init** file in the test folder but the problem persists. It seems that if I run the python3 IDLE, there I can discover both packages while having the path set to be the root directory so at this point I'm not sure why the different behaviors between the two execution modes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)

Comment: Not really, I thought the idea of using __init__.py in both modules is to not have to do environment setting inside the executing python script itself and it seems like an improper solution.

Comment: Assuming that submodule1 is a directory, you need to put an __init__.py there as well. I.e.
`--submodule1
    - __init__.py
    - files` (sorry about messed-up formatting)

Comment: So in order for say unit.py to have access fo files in submodule 1 it has to have an __init__ there too? But the error that I'm getting is that it doesn't even find the source_code module when do the import statement