# ImportError: How do I import a python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I've tried importing a Python module and failed. Here's my folder hierarchy:

```
package/
  folder/
    a.py
  utils/
    b.py
```

In module `a.py` I've tried importing `b.py` but received an `ImportError`.

How do I use function `test` from module `b` to `a.py`?

Files:

***a.py***

```
def usetest():
    test()
```

***b.py***

```
def test():
    print("hello world")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'no module named "app\_one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497278/how-to-fix-no-module-named-app-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing of Python modules can be done with a few different syntaxes:

- A simple `import ...` statement: `import package.utils.b` will now let you use `package.utils.b.test()`. Unfortunately it's quite long.
- An `import ... as ...` statement: `import package.utils.b as b` will let you use `b.test()`.
- A `from ... import ...` statement: `from package.utils.b import test` will let you use `test()`.
- A `from ... import ... as ...` statement: `from package.utils.b import test as test_me` will let you use `test_me()`.

All of these options will run the exact same function. Try putting them at the top of `a.py`.

Specifying the whole path, `package.utils.b` is called absolute form. You  can also import in relative form:

- `import ..utils.b as b` will let you use `b.test()`. Notice the 2 dots at the start, saying **go up one folder**.
- `from ..utils.b import test` will let you use `test()`.
- `from ..utils.b import test as test_me` will let you use `test_me()`.

Each dot at the start specifies go up one folder, except one, which says "this folder".

If the main file you try to run is inside the package (`a.py`), you should switch to the directory that contains package, and run the file using `-m`. In your case, switch to the directory that contains `package`, and run `python -m package.folder.a`.

For more information about importing modules, see the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

You can also dynamically import Python modules using their full path. It's more advanced and won't be covered in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
package/ 
  folder/
    a.py
  utils/
    b.py
```

**import:**

if package is your main folder then use below syntax to import modules.

```
import utils.b as b
b.test() 
**or** 
from utils import b
**or**
To import only method
from utils.b import test
**or**
with alias name
from utils.b import test as my_test (my_test is the method alias name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import :

`import folder.b as b b.test()` or `from folder.b import test` or with alias name `from folder.b import test as my_test` (my_test is the alias name)

If the main file you try to run is inside the package (a.py), you should switch to the directory that contains package, and run the file using `-m`